# Load external config, and use this config for another http call

Tags: angular

For our application we need the read our configuration from an external url, say http://myhost/config.json. This configuration file contains an apiUrl which we should for use all other http requests (Rest).

I tried to use the APP_INITIALIZER with an factory method which calls our service to load the config. This returns an Observable.

When we open our page a get request is executed to get all our customers. This is done via an http request which should use the apiUrl from the config.

However, the system doesn't wait till the first call (to get the config) is ready, so the apiUrl is not available yet.

One option is to wrap each call something like (pseudo):

```
this.configService.getConfig().subscribe(config => {
   this.customerService.getCustomers(config);
})
```

This is not prefered because other developers should just call the customerService directly, and shouldn't bother about the config.

It should be nice when we can inject the Config object in the constructor and use it directly. Is this possible?

If not, how can I make sure the config is available for all other API calls (loaded on startup) ? Something like a synchronized http.get request.

Angular version 4.3.4

Comment: Please give a [mcve], a promise in APP_INITIALIZER should certainly get resolved.

Comment: It is getting resolved but it finishes after the second call to get the customers

Comment: I mean before the rest of the app starts - if that's not working, raise an issue on GitHub (see e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14615).

Comment: It looks like the same problem. So normally all APP_INITIALIZERS should be resolved before proceding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when I convert the observable to a promise it waits correctly.

```
return configObservable.toPromise();
```